# Javascript scroll on anchor click not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have [this Javascript file](https://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/themes/nevada-child/javascripts/animations.js?ver=cc5f7dfe5467fd9489f778f19ec888c9):

```
// .scroll to anchors 
jQuery(".scroll").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var hash = href.split('#');
    var url_hash = '#' + hash[1];
    if (jQuery(url_hash).length > 0) {
        var offset = (jQuery(window).width()<769) ? 20 : 65;
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(url_hash).offset().top-offset
        }, 1000);
    } else{
        location.href = href;
    }
});
```

enqueued on [this page](https://www.orsgroup.com.au/careers/faqs/), which contains the following HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#one">How do I apply to work with you?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#two">Do I need to address selection criteria?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#three">Is there a closing date for applications for your positions?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#four">Who can I contact if I have any questions about one of your advertised positions?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#five">How will I know if my application for a position with you is successful?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#six">How do I find out the salary range of a position you have advertised?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#seven">Do you offer psychology supervision for new graduates?</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#eight">Are you able to provide sponsorship for my visa?</a></li>
</ol>

<p><a id="one" name="one"></a></p>

<p><strong>How do I apply to work with you?
</strong><em><br>
All vacancies are advertised through the Current Vacancies section of our website. If you wish to express a general interest in working with us, we highly recommend you </em><a href="https://www.livehire.me/join/ors/careers"><em>join our Live Hire Talent Community</em></a><em>. We always have new opportunities, and will always look to our talent community before advertising. The best way to be at the front of the line for future and current vacancies is to take a moment to create a private web resume and join our livehire talent community.</em><a id="two" name="two"></a></p>

<p><strong>Do I need to address selection criteria?</strong><u> <br>
</u>
<em>No, you are not required to address any specific selection criteria to apply for a job.</em><a id="three" name="three"></a></p>

<p><strong>Is there a closing date for applications for your positions? </strong><em><br>
Most positions do not have a specific closing date, however some can be filled quite quickly, so we suggest you submit your application as early as possible.</em><a id="four" name="four"></a></p>

<p><strong>Who can I contact if I have any questions about one of your advertised positions?</strong><em><br>
You can contact our recruitment team at any time via </em><a href="mailto:careers@orsgroup.com.au">careers@orsgroup.com.au</a> <a id="five" name="five"></a></p>

<p><strong>How will I know if my application for a position with you is successful?</strong><a href="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/faq/how-will-i-know-if-my-application-is-successful/"><br>
</a><em>If you are shortlisted for an interview, you will receive a request to complete a recruitment assessment within 4 weeks of submitting your application. Due to the high volume of applications we receive, if you have not heard back from us within 4 weeks, you have been unsuccessful for the position.</em><a id="six" name="six"></a></p>

<p><strong>How do I find out the salary range of a position you have advertised?</strong><a href="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/faq/how-do-i-find-out-the-salary-range-of-a-position/"><br>
</a><em>We pay above award rates for all positions. Unfortunately our recruitment team are unable to give you an exact range as it is dependent on the skills, experience and qualifications of the successful applicant.</em><a id="seven" name="seven"></a></p>

<p><strong>Do you offer psychology supervision for new graduates?</strong><a href="http://www.orsgroup.com.au/faq/do-you-offer-psychology-supervision-for-new-graduates/"><br>
</a><em>Yes, we offer supervision arrangements, often as part of your offer of employment. You will need to discuss this with the hiring manager.</em><a id="eight" name="eight"></a></p>

<p><strong>Are you able to provide sponsorship for my visa?</strong><br>
<em>This is highly dependent on the position you are applying for, your skills, qualifications and experience and your location. If you require sponsorship, please make this clear in your application or email <a href="mailto:careers@orsgroup.com.au">careers@orsgroup.com.au</a></em></p>
```

However, whenever any of the links are clicked, the browser does not *scroll*, it jumps.

When the links are clicked, I want the browser to scroll to the anchor tag.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/xox4ooaL/1/).

Help appreciated.

Comment: why are you writing `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: @Alex, because Wordpress demands it. `$` is reserved for Wordpress.

Comment: then make a wrapper. this is not good code!

Comment: Your code is working fine. Just include jquery in the fiddle and test.

Comment: For your server just include the click code inside document ready and test again, as you calling animation.js in head tag before the DOM is loaded fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/xox4ooaL/2/

I changed the functionality of the js a little, and cut away some of all the links and stuff, to give you the general idea of how it could work using data-attributes.
Also $ doesen't work in Wordpress as you said yourself, but when working in Wordpress wrap the function like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Do stuff
});
```